# Update tableview datasource when tapping back item on navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uinavigationbar

**How can I update the datasource array for a tableview when the back button is tapped on a second view?**

I didnt see how to use seques/prepare/unwind on this case. I tried UINavigationControllerDelegate too and had no success.

*Scenario:*

First VC has a tableview with invoices information. When tap on a cell it shows a second VC with a particular invoice information.

Second VC has an action to make payment. When tap on make payment it shows a third VC (a modal).

After tapping make payment on the third VC, it return to the second VC (unwind). It works.

When Im back on the second VC, there is a back button (< Invoices) that I would like to go back to the first VC(invoices). Going back works. The problem is that I need to update the datasource when taping back on the navigation bar.

Save button works too. It updates the datasource (segues/unwind)

[image: Story Board]

*VC1 members:*

```
var invoices = [Invoice]()
var client: Client?
var invoice: Invoice?
var filteredInvoices = [Invoice]()
```

*VC2 members:*

```
var invoice: Invoice?
var client: Client?
var invoiceItems : [InvoiceItem] = [InvoiceItem]()
```

VC3 members:

```
var amountPaid: Decimal = 0.00
var totalInvoice: Decimal = 0.00
var dateTransaction: String? = nil
var invoice: Invoice?
```

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?s=1|137.5666

Comment: ... or, if the invoice has been persisted somehow,  refresh the model in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: rmaddy, i see nothing about back button. just segues. Segues work on add, sabe... not on back on nav bar.

Comment: shallowThought, i tried it, but the thingg is, i cant send the data back from 2 to 1. it goes nil all the time. It prints nav deleg.

extension InvoiceViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        print("nav deleg")
        (viewController as? InvoicesViewController)?.invoice = invoice 
    }

Comment: @RenanAguiar There are plenty of answers that don't use segues. The point is to give you ideas about using delegation to pass data back.

Comment: rmaddy, im not being rude but i couldnt see an answer for that case. When Save is pressed, it works. The problem is only on the back buttom!

Answer (score 0):

## Detect Back button pressed:

```
class SomeViewController : UIViewController {
    
    override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
        
        super.didMove(toParentViewController: parent)
        
        //Back button pressed
        if parent == nil {
            
            //Update your data source here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not even called when i get back.

Comment: is the destination view controller pushed ? like `navigationController?.pushViewController(someVC, animated: true)`

Comment: from invoices to invoice, VC1 to VC2 ==> let destination = segue.destination as? InvoiceViewController,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row AND from invoice to makepayment. VC2 to VC3==>         let payButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Make Payment", style: .default, handler: { action in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "makePayment", sender: self)})

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by unwinding from VC3 (make payment) to VC1 (invoices).

**Why?** It makes more sense after entering a payment to go back to the invoice list and not the invoice detail.

I check if its getting back from detail(VC2) or makepayment(VC3) and make the appropriate calls for every scenario.